# can you get the raw string using input() to have python correctly open text files?

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to make a python script (PyCharm, python version 3.9) which you can write and read any document on my laptop, however, the backslashes in the path of the text file are being read incorrectly when i use it as:

```py
global file
    
def start():
    global file
    print("text file:")
    file = input()
    print("type:")
    m = input()
    if m == 'r':
       read()
    
    def read():
        with open(file, 'a+') as f:
            f.seek(0)
            print(f.read())
```

the console when i run it is:

```
script >> text file:
me >> "C:\Users\mylan\Downloads\test.txt"
script >> type: 
me >> r
```

[image: screenshot if its not clear, didnt know how to explain it]

The error I'm facing is:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '"C:\\Users\\mylan\\Downloads\\test.txt"'
```

I have already searched for related questions and answers but could only find a solution using a r in front:

```
file = r"C:\Users\mylan\Downloads\test.txt
```

The problem with this, however, is that the file that is read is set in code instead of coming from the input, so, is it possible to get the effect of using r"C:..." while using `input()` ?

Comment: Are you typing two backslashes when you enter the filename? You don't need to do that. Escaping is only needed in string literals in programs, not when reading from the terminal or a file.

Comment: When you're typing the filename at the `input()` prompt, don't type two backslashes and don't type the quotes.

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: In Python 2.x you needed to do these things, because `input()` would evaluate what you typed (it used `raw_input()` to get the raw input string). Python 3.x doesn't do this, and its `input()` function is equivalent to the old `raw_input()`.

Comment: This: `'"C:\\Users\\myl\\Downloads\\test.txt"'` indicates you typed the double-quotes around the entry. Don’t do that. The double backslashes just mean that a *single* backslash is present in the string, and it isn’t part of an escape code, so that is normal.

Comment: **DO NOT** post code as a screenshot. It is hard to read and we can't copy/paste the text. Also, you should include relevant facts such as the Python version you are using. Lastly, in this case you should have also shown us what you typed in response to the `input()` call.

Comment: I think your description points to the problem, as @MarkTolonen indicates: `me >> "C:\Users\mylan\Downloads\test.txt"` - exactly this, you're typing the double quotes. You'd do that on a command line like Command Prompt, to avoid it using any spaces to break it up, but you shouldn't do it here. The name doesn't have double quotes in it.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, it was indeed that, when i copied the path it added quotation marks so  problem resolved